# Odd Script File Trying to be Loaded

Tags: multisite, scripts

This is an odd query I have and wondered if anybody can shed some light on it?

We have a number WordPress multi-site (formally Mu) install, but on nearly all the sites on multiple installs we are getting this script tag...

```
<script src='http://[parent-domain]/?dm=[random-string]&amp;action=load&amp;blogid=1&amp;siteid=1&amp;t=401255033&amp;back=[this-sites-domain' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I was wondering if anybody knows what this is all about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In **Network Admin > Settings > Domain Mapping > Domain Options**, uncheck **Remote Login**. That should also remove it.

In my case, the "script" just retrieves the home page (html), causing a script error and a lot of wasted resources on every page view. Similar complaints in [Does Domain Mapping plugin insert javascript on headers?](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-mu-domain-mapping-domain-mapping-javascript?replies=15).

Answer (score 3):

It is added by the Domain Mapping Plugin and i believe (i might be wrong) it is used to log users into all MU sites with a single login.

to remove it:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'remove_unwanted_js');
function remove_unwanted_js(){

    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'remote_login_js_loader' );

}
```